# useState not updating correctly, logging all objects to the console instead of the selected id, and repeatedly logging the initial object

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a pokemone math game and I have a side bar with small icons for each pokemon. Use state is hooked up to my map, but it's not updating the content. It just shows nothing except for the initial state. I've tried manually inputting an object index and then it displays the info so all the props are drilled/state lifted correctly it's just not picking up the right id on selection and I'm not sure why. I'm assuming it's something wrong with the mapping? Since the other parts work properly, or maybe my objects.

I console logged "selectedPokemon" and got the initial state (object index 0) over and over again like maybe fifteen of them. Then on click it logs all of my objects at once and does that two times. Why is it doing that??

```
import "./styles.css";
import { pokemons } from "./Pokemons.js";

import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedPokemon, setSelectedPokemon] = useState(pokemons[0]);

  function handleSelection(pokemons) {
    setSelectedPokemon(pokemons);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <SideBar onSelection={handleSelection} />
      <Main selectedPokemon={selectedPokemon} />
    </div>
  );
}



function SideBar({ onSelection }) {
  return (
    <div className="side-bar">
      <div className="tabs">
        {pokemons.map((pokemon) => (
          <Littlemons
            pokemons={pokemon.id}
            key={pokemon.id}
            image={pokemon.littleimg}
            onSelection={onSelection}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Littlemons({ image, onSelection }) {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => onSelection(pokemons)}>
      <img src={image} style={{ width: "160px" }} />
    </button>
  );
}

function Main({ selectedPokemon }) {

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <img src={selectedPokemon.image} style={{ width: "300px" }} />
      <div className="solve">
        Solve the Math Problem to evolve {selectedPokemon.name}
      </div>
      <form>
        <div className="math">
          {selectedPokemon.problem}
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="?"
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" value="Send">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: `onClick={() => onSelection(pokemons)}` In this code from Littlemons, what does the `pokemons` variable contain? You did pass a prop in named pokemons, but you're not using it.

Comment: The prop for pokemons.id which is the array of objects

Comment: `function Littlemons({ image, onSelection }) {` you're not using the pokemons prop.

Comment: `function Littlemons({ image, onSelection, pokemons }) {`

This right? Did add it. Didn't fix though. (And drilled pokemons through sidebar also. Its still not happy)